# Magento 2 get customer by payment id

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment

How can I get the object of customer if I have the payment id?

```
$payment_id = 3;
```

Table Location is `sales_order_payment`. `$payment_id` is `entity_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you need to get this in a class. And that class is `Vendor\Module\Model\MyClass`.
Make your class look like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class MyClass
{
     protected $orderPaymentRepository;
     protected $orderRepository;
     protected $customerRepository;
     public function __construct(
         \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderPaymentRepositoryInterface $orderPaymentRepository,
         \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
         \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepository $customerRepository

     ) {
          $this->orderPaymentRepository = $orderPaymentRepository;
          $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
          $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
     }

     public function getCustomerByPaymentId($paymentId)
     {
          try {
              $payment = $this->orderPaymentRepository->get($paymentId);
              $order = $this->orderRepository->get($payment->getParentId());
              $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($order->getCustomerId());
              return $customer;
          } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
              return null; //the payment or order or customer does not exist
          }
     }
}
```